# SparqlResultSet giving {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

Tags: sparql, dotnetrdf

This is the code and the query that i am using..

```
SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpointeds = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new  Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");

SparqlResultSet resultss = endpointeds.QueryWithResultSet("
PREFIX dbp-ont:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?location, str(?label) 
{ ?location  dbp-ont:country <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Italy> .
  ?location a ?type filter ( ?type = dbp-ont:ArchitecturalStructure || 
  ?type=dbp-ont:Place     || ?type=dbp-ont:NaturalPlace || ?type=dbp-ont:Mountain || 
  ?type=dbp-ont:Volcano || ?type=dbp-ont:Village || ?type=dbp-ont:AdministrativeRegion 
 || ?type=dbp-ont:Island  || ?type=dbp-ont:Continent) .
 ?location foaf:name ?label  filter (lang(?label)=" + "en" + ").} order by ?location limit 10");
```

I know that the query work well because i have already tried it in Virtuoso, i dont know why it is giving me this error, 
 working with visual studio 2012 thanks.

Comment: The dotNetRDF documentation covers how to debug HTTP errors like this to get more information to help diagnose the issue - https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/HowTo/Debug%20HTTP%20Communication - In your specific case @AndyS has already pointed out the error in your query

Answer (score 2):

See the same question, with answer, at [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/23254/sparqlresultset-giving-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403075229/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/23254/sparqlresultset-giving-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request)